# Unable to attach instances to, TG's with error: Inappropriate value for attribute "target_group_arn": string required

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to attach instances to multiple target groups with ARN's fetched from Output. But I am unable to, with error "Inappropriate value for attribute "target_group_arn": string required".

```
  count            = length(data.terraform_remote_state.app.outputs.target_group_names)
  target_group_arn = element(data.terraform_remote_state.app.outputs.target_group_arns, count.index)
  target_id        = module.ec2.id[0]
}
```

**Following is the error I get:**

```
 on main.tf line 115, in resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "tg_attachment":
 115:   target_group_arn = element(data.terraform_remote_state.app.outputs.target_group_arns, count.index)
    |----------------
    | count.index is 0
    | data.terraform_remote_state.app.outputs.target_group_arns is tuple with 1 element

Inappropriate value for attribute "target_group_arn": string required.
```

**Actual Output for reference:**

```
      + [
          + [
              + "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:xxxxxxx:targetgroup/xxxxx/xxxx",
              + "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:xxxxxxx:targetgroup/yyyyy/yyyy",
            ],
        ],
    ]
```

length of `length(data.terraform_remote_state.app.outputs.target_group_names)`
is 2 currently.

Need some help in resolving this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Actual Output for reference` shows that your ARNs is list of single element which is the actual list of ARNs. Thus you should be able to get them as follows:

```
target_group_arn = element(data.terraform_remote_state.app.outputs.target_group_arns[0], count.index)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried it, but it's trying to attach instances to just the first TG and not others.

Comment: @reddy0969 Sorry, not sure what are the "others". This depends on what is `length(data.terraform_remote_state.app.outputs.target_group_names)`, which is not shown in your question.

Comment: sorry, I just updated my question. currently, the length is 2 with 2 target group arn's.

Comment: Ignore my comments. This solution works, I had to update it similarly for count i.e :  count = length(data.terraform_remote_state.app.outputs.target_group_arns[0]).